# Unfortunately newsample4 stopped in android

Tags: android-emulator

> 1-When i run it,emulator does not allow to show my button.
>   2-this is my code:
>           package fatemi.prj.newsample4;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {        /*main activity*/
Button btn=new Button(this);
private OnClickListener btnOnclickListener= new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {              /* click button for showing date*/
updateTime();
}
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btn.setOnClickListener(btnOnclickListener);
updateTime();
setContentView(btn);
}
private void updateTime() {              /* defne update function*/
btn.setText(new Date().toString());
}
}
```